# Custom class not shown in the storyboard identity inspector

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I created in my app  a new class named `EmpresasTableViewController`, and in the storyboard I copied `CategoriasViewController` to EmpresasTableViewController, I just want to assign the class `EmpresasTableViewController` to `EmpresasTableViewController` in the storyboard, but the name `EmpresasViewController` doesn't appear in the `Identity Inspector`.

There are no errors after creating the class, but why is it not shown as a class in the storyboard `Identity Inspector` under `Custom Class`?, all other view controllers are shown.

Comment: Sometimes you have to save first, or even quit the project and open it again, in order to get the project to be indexed again so that the storyboard sees the class. In spite of appearances, Interface Builder (interface) and Xcode (code) are still two quite different things, and they don't communicate all that well.

Comment: Did you try to clean the project?

Comment: @GlaucoNeves, cleaning the project doesn't solved the issue. I have closed the project and opened it again, and the class is shown, thank you in any case.

Comment: @matt, you were right, after closing and opening again the project, the class is shown..thank you, please put your comment as answer to my question and I will select it as the first right answer.

Comment: No problem, you can uptick @reecon's answer if you like. I'm glad I was able to help! This happens to me so often, and drives me crazy every time...

Comment: @matt, I do appreciate that you were the first, and I also appreciate the answer from reecon, but to be honest, I think you should be awarded with my reputation points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, all your files needs to be saved.

What you can try is:

**Option 1.** Close and reopen `Xcode` with your project.

**Option 2.** Clean your project and build it again.

**Option 3.** Force `Xcode` to do the indexing of your project once again:

> Open the `Organizer` (Window > Organizer) and select the `Projects` mode.
>   Select your project in the left-hand view and then click the `Delete...`
>   button for the project's `Derived Data`.
>
> This will delete the code sense index for the project and force `Xcode`
>   to rebuild the index, which may fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing which worked for me was to:

1. Create a new group (folder) I called it Controller2
2. Right click "Add file to ...
3. Select all the class files
4. Remove (reference) controller group
5. Rename group controller2 to controller

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers on the entire internet from Africa to Japan to Canada solved my issue. Zero. Tried all the hacks and tips and tricks known to the human race. This is because all of the answers pertain to projects with a single target.

Two hours, 50 gray hairs, and many tears later I realized it was because I created a watchOS **WKInterfaceController class** with the **same name** as an already existing iOS **ViewController class**. Xcode gives zero warning about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the xib as text.  The CustomClass attribute is on the view, change it manually here then switch back to the interface builder view.

Answer (score 0):

You can input your controller in Class column directly and manually.It's work. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your view has the right inheritance class as the same storyboard view .
if it is a table , make sure that you inherit from UIViewController class .. 
It solved my problem after i did everything . may it help

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

Make sure you have UITableViewController selected and not UIViewController, that was my solution after looking for about 30min, I hope this helps

[picture of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeqpm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another issue is if your Xcode project is stored on an external drive/SSD. I am experiencing this bug with `Xcode 11.3.1`. Simply move the project to the local Mac storage and open it. Interface builder will now work properly.

Sometimes it also helps to clean the project and rebuild. I've noticed that interface builder doesn't always update properly... must be another bug. (I miss the days when Xcode updates were reliable).

Answer (score 0):

If the custom class in question is not a ***subclass*** of the type of class you want to associate it, it wont auto populate in Identity Inspector.
That is, for view controllers the custom class should be *UIViewController*.
For table view cells it should be a *subclass* of *UITableViewCell*.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I've had two classes with the same name for Mac Os and iOs platforms, but with different targets. XCode doesn't seem to recognise that. Renaming classes for one of the platforms solved the problem for me.
Also check and make sure that you've set the correct target for your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit *UIViewController* in your class. My mistake was to inherit *UICollectionViewCell*. And that concluded that error.