# there is Jitsi meeting in objective C

Tags: objective-c, jitsi, jitsi-meet

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fqm0.png)

   I am building a Jitsi meeting in objective C and this is the bug

   - unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103008570 2021-01-13    16:10:38.421002+0700 hyper[10246:2399644] *** Terminating app due to
     uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
     setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103008570'
     *** First throw call stack: (0x19fc619d4 0x1b3612b54 0x19fb71bac 0x1a24f903c 0x19fc64018 0x19fc65f8c 0x1003b7680 0x1a1dff110
     0x1a1e036f8 0x1a1e03ad8 0x1a2502814 0x1a2502028 0x1a2502ebc
     0x1a2513b14 0x1a2726d54 0x1a19e30b0 0x1a24c5fe4 0x1a24c6388
     0x1a2007320 0x1ae5f77c4 0x1ae61f1f0 0x1ae604f20 0x1ae61ef04
     0x100695528 0x1006989f0 0x1ae643f20 0x1ae643be8 0x1ae6440bc
     0x19fbe1be0 0x19fbe1ae0 0x19fbe0e8c 0x19fbdb3d0 0x19fbdab90
     0x1b5efd598 0x1a24c4638 0x1a24c9bb8 0x1003c0484 0x19f8b9588)
     libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
     NSException    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]:
     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103008570' terminating with
     uncaught exception of type NSException

   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView join:]: unrecognized
   selector sent to instance 0x14080d980' terminating with uncaught
   exception of type NSException

This is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    

//    // Attach this controller as the delegate.
    JitsiMeetView *jitsiView = (JitsiMeetView*)self.view;
    jitsiView.delegate = self;

    // Join the room.
    JitsiMeetConferenceOptions *options
        = [JitsiMeetConferenceOptions fromBuilder:^(JitsiMeetConferenceOptionsBuilder *builder) {
            builder.serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://meet.jit.si/RomanticEmployersFilterMoreover"];
         //   builder.room = self.room;
        }];
    [jitsiView join:options];
    jitsiView.alpha = 0;
 
    
}
```

Comment: `self.view` is not set as a `JitsiMeetView` in your Xib/Storyboard. Also, copy/paste your error next time, instead of screenshot

Comment: I new to this. Can you explain more detail for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862194/1801544 Select `view`, change its class to `JitsiMeetView`.  `(JitsiMeetView*)self.view` means "Compiler, I'm telling you that view is a `JitsiMeetView`, consider it as such. If that's not the case, that's not my problem, you might crash if needed later".

Comment: I already set that this is not the solution

Comment: And yet, it seems to be so. The question, is how did you into your ViewController?

Comment: I just added more detail about my bug please check it out and help me !!

Comment: I set it is initial ViewController